# How to order inner keysource in linq vb group join

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I'm trying to join a table to itself using a group join and VB.NET. The code below works and sorts the outer (parent) rows but I'd like to guarantee the sequence of the inner (child) rows:

```
Dim queryEthnicities = From aParentEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity _
   Group Join aChildEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity On aChildEthnicity.ParentID Equals aParentEthnicity.EthnicityID Into EthnicityList = Group _
   Where aParentEthnicity.RoundID.Equals(aRoundID) Order By aParentEthnicity.Sort
```

I found something similar for C# at [Ordering inner keysource in simple/unnamed C# LINQ group join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952979/ordering-inner-keysource-in-simple-unnamed-c-sharp-linq-group-join) 
but haven't found a way to do this in VB - grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Right now I can't run and test your code to be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to provide when asking a question:

```
Public Class edata

    Public Ethnicity As Ethnicity() = _
    { _
        New Ethnicity() With { .EthnicityID = 4, .ParentId = 1, .RoundID = 3, .Sort = 8 }, _
        New Ethnicity() With { .EthnicityID = 3, .ParentId = 1, .RoundID = 4, .Sort = 5 }, _
        New Ethnicity() With { .EthnicityID = 1, .RoundID = 2 } _
    }

End Class

Public Class Ethnicity

    Public ParentID As Integer
    Public EthnicityID As Integer
    Public RoundID As Integer
    Public Sort As Integer

End Class

Sub Main

    Dim edata = New edata()
    Dim aRoundID = 2

    Dim queryEthnicities = _
        From aParentEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity _
        Group Join aChildEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity On aChildEthnicity.ParentID Equals aParentEthnicity.EthnicityID Into EthnicityList = Group _
        Where aParentEthnicity.RoundID.Equals(aRoundID) _
        Order By aParentEthnicity.Sort

End Sub
```

When this code runs it produces:

[image: original]

To ensure the order of the inner data you need to change the query like so:

```
Dim queryEthnicities = _
    From aParentEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity _
    Group Join aChildEthnicity In edata.Ethnicity.OrderBy(Function (x) x.Sort) On aChildEthnicity.ParentID Equals aParentEthnicity.EthnicityID Into EthnicityList = Group _
    Where aParentEthnicity.RoundID.Equals(aRoundID) _
    Order By aParentEthnicity.Sort
```

Now it produces:

[image: ordered]

Comment: Just what I needed - and I appreciate the feedback about posting as well

Comment: @MikeDiggins - If it worked for you don't forget to up-vote and select as accepted answer.